# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in passing jsonfile to a cponent

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, undefined

I'm trying to read a JSON file and trying to pass it on to the component however I am getting this error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined and I cant seem to find what the issue is.

here is the code i have created:

```js
export default function Questions() {

    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [showScore, setShowScore] = useState(false);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const quizQuestions = quiz.questions;

    const handleAnswerOptionClick = (isCorrect) => {
        if (isCorrect) {
            setScore(score + 1);
        }

        const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < quizQuestions.length) {
            setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        } else {
            setShowScore(true);
        }
    };
    
    quizQuestions.map((quizQuestions)=> {
    return (
        <div className='questions'>
      

            <div className="questions_row">
                {showScore ? (
                    <div className='score-section'>
                        You scored {score} out of {quizQuestions.length}
                    </div>
                ) : (
                        <>
                            <QuestionsProduct
                                title="Introduction to Programming2"
                                questioNum={currentQuestion + 1}
                                question={quizQuestions[currentQuestion].quizQuestions.questionText}
                                answers={quizQuestions[currentQuestion].quizQuestions.answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                                    <label onClick={() => handleAnswerOptionClick(quizQuestions.answerOption.isCorrect)}
                                        type="checkbox">{answerOption.quizQuestions.answerText}</label>
                                ))}
                            />
                        </>
                                   
                    )}
            </div> 
        </div>);
    })
}
```

and the json file name is quiz.json. I currenntly have this data internaly however i want to create more questions therefore json file will be ideal. here is the json file created

```js
[{ "questions" : {
        "questionText": "What is the capital of France?",
        "answerOptions": [
            { "answerText": "New York", "isCorrect": false },
            { "answerText": "London", "isCorrect": false },
            { "answerText": "Paris", "isCorrect": true },
            { "answerText": "Dublin", "isCorrect": false }
        ]
    },
    
        "questionText2": "What is the capital of France 2?",
        "answerOptions": [
            { "answerText": "New York", "isCorrect": false },
            { "answerText": "London", "isCorrect": false },
            { "answerText": "Paris", "isCorrect": true },
            { "answerText": "Dublin", "isCorrect": false }
        ]
     }
]
```

Comment: does quizQuestions has data to map? And please add more code and from where you are getting questions data

Comment: yes its readoing from a jason file.  here is the whole code:

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a null check

```
quizQuestions && quizQuestions.map((quizQuestion)=> { return ()}
```

> Don't use the same `quizQuestions` inside map as well

Answer (score 0):

this error comes because quizQuestions has null values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function to get data from Json like following:

```
  const [quizQuestions, setQuizQuestions]=useState([]);
  const getQuestionData=()=>{
    fetch('data.json'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
        setQuizQuestions(myJson)
      });
  }
```

Then call this function from useEffect:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    getQuestionData()
  },[])
```

Then render data as following:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
     {
       quizQuestions && quizQuestions.length>0 && 
          quizQuestions.map((item)=>
              <p>{item.title}</p>
          )
     }
    </div>
  );
```